# fill out white space with a line

Tags: html, css

How can I create a underline that fills up the white space between the end of a text line and the end of a DIV's width.

I'm trying the following:

I want the product line to break when the screen gets smaller. I want the price to stay lined out to the right and be underlined. The white space between the last word (Mayo) and the price must automatically be filled with a underline.

Big screen:
Old Cheese – Salad, Avocado, Egg, Herbal Mayo......................500

Smaller screen:
Old Cheese – Salad, Avocado, Egg, 
Herbal Mayo..........................................500

Extra small screen: 
Old Cheese – Salad, 
Avocado, 
Egg, Herbal 
Mayo...........................500

I have the following markup:

### HTML

```
<div class="productline">
  <div class="product">
    Old Cheese – Salad, Avocado, Egg, Herbal Mayo
  </div>
  <div class="line">&nbsp</div>
  <div class="price">500</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.productline {
    width:300px;
}
.product {
    display:table-cell;    
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
.price {
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

### Example

http://jsfiddle.net/florisvl/zV6Yd/

### FIX

http://jsfiddle.net/florisvl/3b7Tr/

Comment: I see what you are trying to do but this actually looks like a pretty good _semantic_ use for a `table`. Why not use one? It would solve quite a few of your alignment issues, as they are designed to fit content in the way you seem to be trying to do with CSS.

Comment: I tried using a table. But also with the table I could not get the white space to be filled with a line that fills to the and of the width.

Comment: Do you think that you could clean this up to be phased as a question?

Comment: Yes! Sorry new to Stack Overflow. I'm on it!

Comment: @florisvl A dotted border would work well.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you want, but is this close? http://jsfiddle.net/florisvl/zV6Yd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of a trick, but it works (at least tested in FF):

http://jsfiddle.net/dVtCc/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>
                Old Cheese – Salad, Avocado, Egg, Herbal Mayo
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="price">
            <span>
                500
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td{
    border-bottom: 3px dotted black;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 0;
}

td.price{
    text-align: right;
}

td > span{
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -5px;
}
```

The tricks is that the dotted border actually spans the entire bottom of the row, but the `span`s are positioned to cover up the border directly below them.

Comment: Same thing can be accomplished using divs, but it does seem like this is tabular data to me too.

Comment: I like this answer. I was considering suggesting something along these lines, but I wonder how this will look across all devices. I always get nervous trying to get small overlaps like this, since this kind of 'pixel precision' often goes wrong on the web. Incidentally this also works in Opera 12, not that anyone but me cares. :)

Comment: @crush Agreed.  I assume it will be something like this with multiple rows:  http://jsfiddle.net/dVtCc/10/

Comment: Hard to satisfy the criteria *I want the product line to break when the screen gets smaller.* without using this approach it would seem.

Comment: Great! Tnx @JamesMontagne for helping me out solving this question. I fiddled a bit more to get to were I wanted it to be and here is the result http://jsfiddle.net/florisvl/3b7Tr/

Answer (score 0):

I used a `float: left` on the product and a `float: right` on the price to achieve this effect. [See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dVtCc/45/)

***This requires the use of a [`clearfix`](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) implementation.***

### HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="product clearfix">
        <div class="name">Old Cheese - Salad, Avocado, Egg, Herbal Mayo</div>
        <div class="price">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product clearfix">
        <div class="name">Stuff, stuff and more stuff</div>
        <div class="price">100</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product clearfix">
        <div class="name">And a bit more</div>
        <div class="price">200</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.menu {
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
}

.product {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.product .name {
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.product .price {
    float: right;
}


/* Clearfix */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

The wrapping effect isn't quite as nice as it is with the use of tables.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not exactly what you are looking for but close. I think I have seen this solved before with pseudo-elements but I cannot find it by searching on SO.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zV6Yd/54/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="productline">
    <div class="product">
        Old Cheese – Salad, Avocado, Egg, Herbal Mayo
    </div>
    <div class="price">500</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.productline {
    width:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.product {   
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:60%;
    line-height:1em;
    border-bottom:1px dashed black;
}

.price {
    vertical-align:bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    width:35%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    line-height:1em;
    border-bottom:1px dashed black;    
}
```